# Compiling netcat on AIX

Tags: c, makefile, aix, netcat

I have been trying to compile netcat.c on AIX for some time (using the command `make aix`), but the compiler gives me some weird feedback such as :

"netcat.c", line 117.12: 1506-275 (S) Unexpected text 'int' encountered.

when checked the file netcat.c at line 117, I would find the line (second line in code below):

```
#ifdef HAVE_BIND
extern int h_errno;
/* stolen almost wholesale from bsd herror.c */
```

even if I changed the int into char for the same of testing, save the file and re-run the command I get the same error

am I missing something in reading the error code?

Comment: ok, I am looking for gcc online now to install on my machine and will try to compile the code with it instead of cc.

Comment: @A.Rashad, cc will either be the brain-dead compiler that comes with the OS or a link through to xlc. I think gcc _is_ probably the best way to go, expecially if you're wanting to build all the FOSS/Linux-y tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `xlc` (especially older ones), it's normally caused by declarations after statements, something like:

```
i = i + 1;
int x;
```

You probably need to give us a little more context, such as 10 or so lines before the error line.

My advice would be to get `gcc` running on that box if you *are* using an older xlc. IBM makes some fine compilers now but the earlier ones weren't so crash hot (in my opinion).

Comment: it does have declarations in the middle of the code.
should I reconsider defining them in the beginning of each function and try one more time?

Comment: That depends entirely on whether your compiler allows the declarations after statements. I think that was introduced in ISO C99 but don't quote me :-) If your compiler pre-dates that then you will have a problem, hence my suggestion to use an up-to-date xlc or gcc.

Answer (score 1):

When innocent-looking code produces bizarre errors, try running the code through the C preprocessor stage, and looking at it then. Sometimes macros do very funny things.

Also note that a problem on an earlier line (missing semicolon, etc.) might produce an error message on a later line.

Comment: aren't preprocessors written with no semicolons? 

how to run the code with preprocessor stage? any Makefile change required to do so?

PS: I am using cc to compile

Comment: @A.Rashad, Artelius doesn't mean the line immediately preceding (which you've shown us anyway). We need _more_ context to be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The post maybe already a little outdated, but just in case someone else comes along with the same problem ...

Here (AIX 7.1) h_errno is defined as macro in netdb.h.

```
/usr/include/netdb.h:#define h_errno   (*(int *)h_errno_which())
```

Therefore the declaration in netcat.c line 117  does not work.

I just changed the line into

```
#ifndef h_errno
extern int h_errno;
#endif
```

and the compilation worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

@A.Rashad, I moved the HAVE_BIND #ifdef block from line 117 to line 30 which is just under the #include "generic.h" declaration. This permitted the xlc to compile it. The (S)yntax error messages are gone and while there are some (W)arning messages, I do get an nc binary at the end!

hth,

Kevin